# Optimal return type when calling Python function from Rust using PyO3

Tags: rust, pyo3

I am writing a Python module in Rust using PyO3. In one of these Rust functions, I am calling a python function, `my_py_func`, which returns a `numpy.ndarray`, with `dtype=int64` entries, and `shape=(k,2)` for some dynamically determined `k`.

My rust code looks like this.

```rust
let my_py_func_rs = PyModule::import(py, "__main__").unwrap().getattr("my_py_func").unwrap().into();

// input argument to the python function
// my_input_array is a ndarray::Array1<u8>
let args = PyTuple::new(py, &[my_input_array.into_pyarray(py)]);

let output_array: Vec<Vec<usize>> = my_py_func_rs.call1(py, args).unwrap().extract(py).unwrap();
```

This works! Compiles and runs as expected.

But I have a feeling that it's not correct or optimal to use vector of vectors as the data structure. The subsequent operation I want to do on `output_array` is iterating over the rows and doing something based on each row. I want to extract every bit of performance, because the final code will run for many days/weeks.

Will it be faster to use `Array2`? I can't test this because I don't know how to convert the python function output to `Array2`. I am also using the [numpy crate](https://docs.rs/numpy/latest/numpy/index.html) elsewhere in my code, if that is relevant.

What is the fastest datastructure for `output_array`?

Comment: Probably, the really fastest way will be to not do any conversions. Keep the data in numpy format and access its elements via the numpy C API using [`numpy::PyArray`](https://docs.rs/numpy/latest/numpy/array/struct.PyArray.html).

Comment: You can then get `ndarray` views over the data via `array.readonly().as_array()` and `array.readwrite().as_array_mut()`.